# USNCO question - Finding pH of salt solution from pKa of its parent acid

Tags: acid-base, aqueous-solution, hydrolysis

The question from 2017 USNCO is as below:

> What is the $\mathrm{pH}$ of a $\pu{0.25 M}$ solution of $\ce{NaCN}$? (The $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of $\ce{HCN}$ is $9.21$.)
>
> (**A**) $4.91$
> (**B**) $8.61$
> (**C**) $11.30$
> (**D**) $13.40$

The answer sheet states (**C**).

My understandings/reasoning:

- salt hydrolysis: solution of salt derived from strong base and weak acid is basic;
- $\ce{NaCN}$ is derived from the base $\ce{NaOH}$ (strong) and acid $\ce{HCN}$ (weak according to given $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$);
- Solution is basic, so (**A**) is incorrect.

However, I am unable to proceed from here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sodium cyanide is a salt formed by a strong base and a weak acid, so the reduced ionic equation of hydrolysis is

$$\ce{CN- + H2O <=>[$K_\mathrm{h}$] HCN + OH-}$$

$$
\begin{align}
K_\mathrm{h} &= \left.\frac{[\ce{HCN}][\ce{OH-}]}{[\ce{CN-}]} \qquad \right|\cdot \frac{[\ce{H+}]}{[\ce{H+}]}\\
&= \frac{[\ce{HCN}][\ce{OH-}][\ce{H+}]}{[\ce{CN-}][\ce{H+}]}\\
&=\frac{K_\mathrm{w}}{K_\mathrm{a}} \label{eq:1}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$

Sodium cyanide is highly soluble salt, so one can neglect auto-protolysis of water, and also express hydrolysis constant (assuming $[\ce{OH-}] = [\ce{HCN}]$ and $C$ – concentration of sodium cyanide) as follows:

$$K_\mathrm{h} = \frac{[\ce{OH-}]^2}{C-[\ce{OH-}]} \label{eq:2}\tag{2}$$

Equating \eqref{eq:1} and \eqref{eq:2}:

$$\frac{10^{-14}}{10^{-9.21}} = \frac{[\ce{OH-}]^2}{0.25-[\ce{OH-}]}\, ,\label{eq:3}\tag{3}$$

and solving the quadratic equation \eqref{eq:3} for $[\ce{OH-}]$, one can find that $[\ce{OH-}] \approx \pu{2e-3 M}$, $\mathrm{pOH} = 2.70$, hence

$$\mathrm{pH} = 14.00 - \mathrm{pOH} = 14.00 - 2.70 = 11.30$$

Comment: Thank you. I noticed that you used water's dissociation constant at 25°C. However, many questions specify the temperature, while this doesn't, leading me to believe that a temperature-independent solution would be preferred.

Comment: @GeorgeTian There is none unless the problem itself explicitly tells you the temperature or $K_\mathrm{w}$. In the absence of such info, it's safe to assume that $K_\mathrm{w} = 10^{-14}$ and move along.